# For a web app that allows simple image uploads, how should I store the images? Confused about file system vs. cdn

Tags: node.js, web-services, amazon-web-services, heroku, image-uploading

Every search result says something about storing the images in the file system but store the paths in the database, but I'm not sure exactly what "file system" means. Would that mean you have something like:

```
/public (assets)
    /js
    /css
    /img
/app (frontend)
/server (backend)
```

and you'd upload directly to that /public/img directory?

I remember trying something like that in the past with a Node.js app hosted on Heroku, and it wouldn't let me. I had to set up Amazon S3 and upload the images THERE, which leads to my confusion.

Is using something like Amazon S3 the usual practice or do people upload directly to the /img directory (assuming this is the "file system"?) and it just happened to be the case that Heroku doesn't allow this but other hosts do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd characterize the pattern as "store the data in a blob storage service, store a pointer in your database". The uploaded file is the "blob" - once it has left the user's computer and filesystem, is it really a file anymore? :) On the server, a file system can store that "blob". S3 can store that blob. In the first case, you are storing a path. In the second case, you are storing the URL to the S3 object. A database could even store that blob (not at all recommended, though...)

In any case, the question to ask is: "what happens when I need two app servers to support my traffic?". Wherever that blob goes, both app servers need access to it.

In a data center under your control, there are many ways to share a filesystem across servers - network attached storage (NFS- or SMB-mounted volumes), or storage area networks (iSCSI, Fibre Channel). With more limited network/hardware configuration options in cloud-based Infrastructure/Platform-as-a-Service providers, the de facto standard is S3 because it is inexpensive, reliable, easy to use, and can completely offload serving the file from your servers.

For Heroku, though, you don't have much control over the file system. And, know that the file system for each of your dynos is "ephemeral" - it goes away when the dyno restarts. Which will happen when your app goes idle, or every 24 hours, whichever comes first. So that forces the choice a little.

Final point - S3 comes with the ancillary benefit of taking the burden of serving the blob off of your servers. You can also store files directly to S3 from the browser, without routing it through your app (see https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3-upload-node). The benefit in both cases is that those downloads/uploads can take up lots of your application's precious time for stuff that's pretty rote.

Answer (score 2):

Uploading directly to a host file system is generally not a best practice. This is one reason services like S3 are so popular.

If you're using the host file system and ever need more than one instance of a server, the file systems will grow out of sync. Imagine one user uploads 'foo.jpg' to server A (A/app/uploads) and another uploads 'bar.jpg' to server B (B/app/uploads). When either of these images is later requested, the request has a 50% chance of failing, depending on whether the load balancer routes the request to server A or server B.

There are several ancillary benefits to avoiding the host filesystem. For instance, you can set the filesystem serving your app to read-only for increased security. Files are a form of state, and stateless web servers allow you to do things like blow away one instance and deploy another instance to take over its work.

Answer (score 1):

You might find this of help:

https://codeforgeek.com/2014/11/file-uploads-using-node-js/

I used multer in my node.js server file to handle uploading from the front end. Basically I had an html form that would submit the image to the server file, where it would be handled by multer. This actually led it to be saved in the file system (to answer your question concretely, yes, this was to something like the /img directory right in your project file structure). My application is running on heroku, and this feature works on there as well. However, I would not recommending using the file system to store your image like this (I doubt you will have enough space for a large amount of images/files) - using AWS storage or a DB would be better.